# Panama transit visa Cameroonian

Tags: transit-visas, panama, cameroonian-citizens

Am a Cameroonian I obtain a Panama transit visa which I applied through an agent how can I know the authenticity of this transit visa
Regards

Comment: What makes you doubt its authenticity? You could try contacting the issuing consulate for confirmation

Comment: It says [here](https://www.embassyofpanama.org/visas-1) that you should have come personally to have it stamped, have you?